# Smoking and psychedelics in kabbalah?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, tobacco-cig-smoking, marijuana

Many are familiar with stories of great tzaddikim smoking pipes and the like in some sort of kabbalastic rite. I've even heard some chassidic Rebbes having a so called "Kabbalah pipe".  Im curious to know if perhaps marijuana was used to induce meditational states. Other places (including in the books of Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan) have mentioned deep meditational states of Kabbalists brought about through psychedelic substances.

Twofold question: 
Is there some source in kabbalah for the use of any drugs to reach higher levels of connection?

And/or any sources for kabbaltic meditation using smoke?

Comment: Even if there is such a concept it's not going to override ונשמרתם מאד לנפשתיכם

Comment: cannabis is not clasdified as psychedelic substance. The first known psychedelic substance was LSD, lysergic acid, created in the 20th century. This substance is not smocked. There are additional substances coming from american and asiatic continents and there was no importation at this time.

Comment: Heshy's comment is correct. @kouty Don't know what 'classification' you are referring to. Your comment regarding LSD is incorrect. In terms of Jewish historical practice, there are records that seem to suggest some kind of mind altering substances being used by some individuals. They are likely plant based and specific identification is unclear.

Comment: Marijuana usage was common in cooking in eastern European Jewish communities a century ago. It appears by name in halachic responsa for Pesach.

Comment: LSD was first synthesized on November 16, 1938[92] by Swiss chemist Albert Hofmann at the Sandoz Laboratories in Basel, Switzerland

Comment: @Yaacov Deane see above

Comment: @kouty I familiar with the beginning of commercial production you mention. However, Ergot usage from rye, which is the plant source for the synthesized commercial product, was happening long before the 20th century. And none of this is on topic.

Comment: @Yaacov Deane, see wiki for psychedelic. The traditional use of psychedelic was among native americans only

Comment: @kouty See Kykeon. And that is only dealing with the beverage consumed at the Ancient Greek festival celebrated for 2000 years. It attracted people from all around the Mediterranean.