# Are hallucigenics bad?

Tags: liquor-beer, drugs

Logically, it would seem that the use of mushrooms or other psychedelic or hallucigenic drugs would be a bad thing in yiddishkeit. Though some people claim it allows for a great spiritual experience.
Is there anything wrong per se with using these substances?
How does it differ from alcohol (or even coffee!) which is also an addictive substance positing that addiction is the problem?

Comment: Related/Dupes: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/133962/31534 (<-my answer there directly answers this question too) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84394/31534 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/134534/31534

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Judaism/comments/2qx2jl/the_lubavitcher_rebbes_answer_on_lsd_letter/